# XSL - Does evaluating conditional expressions "shortcut"?

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements

Given an XSL 'If' statement:

```
<xsl:if test="a = 'some value' and b = 'another value'">
```

If `a` does not equal `'some value'`, is the value of `b` still checked? (As if the first test is `false`, the only outcome of the `and` is `false`.) This is what languages like C# do - I was wondering if the same goes in XSL. Does it depend on the engine/parser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is called lazy-evaluation or short-circuiting, and xsl supports it. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#booleans

> An and expression is evaluated by
>   evaluating each operand and converting
>   its value to a boolean as if by a call
>   to the boolean function. The result is
>   true if both values are true and false
>   otherwise. **The right operand is not
>   evaluated if the left operand
>   evaluates to false.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is depending on the implementation. But since XSLT is side-effect-free (as opposed to C# and other languages, where a function call chainging some state or even an assignment can be in the expression), this does not matter.

Comment: Yes, but using short-circuiting saves a bit of time, doesn't it?

Comment: Of course, but since the order of execution does not matter, ever more optimizations are possible (such as performing queries estimated to be "cheaper" first etc.)