# Using conditions in XSLT/XPath to avoid a calculation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, saxon, oxygenxml

Suppose I have two functions, one simple and one complex, which I bind to global variables:

```
<xsl:variable name="a" select="eg:quick-func()"/>
<xsl:variable name="b" select="e.g.:very-long-func()"/>
```

I want to avoid calculating $b if $a is true, to avoid a lot of processing time. In testing the three options below (Saxon 9) I find that $b is calculated even when $a is true.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="if ($a) then $a else $b"/>

<xsl:copy-of select="($a,$b)[1]"/>

<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$a">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$a"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$b"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Is there a work-around?

Comment: Consider to tell us exactly which Saxon version you use and then of course which return type the functions have and how you determine that `b` was computed.

Comment: XSLT uses lazy evalution apparently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410057/xsl-does-evaluating-conditional-expressions-shortcut. But it might not work for functions, whose return value is assigned to a variable. Did you try `if/then` / `xsl:choose` around `xsl:variable` of `b`?

Comment: I read your suggestion as turning the global variable into a local one, resulting in invalidation. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:function name="mf:f1" as="node()*">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:param name="bar"/>
  <xsl:message select="'f1 called'"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$input//foo[bar = $bar]"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="mf:f2" as="node()*">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:param name="baz"/>
  <xsl:message select="'f2 called'"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$input//foo[baz = $baz]"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:variable name="a" select="mf:f1(/, 'bar 1')"/>
<xsl:variable name="b" select="mf:f2(/, 'baz 1')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select="if ($a) then $a else $b"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with the input

```
<root>
  <foo>
    <bar>bar 1</bar>
    <baz>baz a</baz>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <bar>bar 2</bar>
    <baz>baz 1</baz>
  </foo>
</root>
```

with Saxon 9.6 HE and the output is

```
f1 called
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><foo>
    <bar>bar 1</bar>
    <baz>baz a</baz>
  </foo>
```

With the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:function name="mf:f1" as="node()*">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:param name="bar"/>
  <xsl:message select="'f1 called'"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$input//foo[bar = $bar]"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="mf:f2" as="node()*">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:param name="baz"/>
  <xsl:message select="'f2 called'"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$input//foo[baz = $baz]"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:variable name="a" select="mf:f1(/, 'bar 1')"/>
<xsl:variable name="b" select="mf:f2(/, 'baz 1')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select="if ($b) then $b else $a"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is

```
f2 called
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><foo>
    <bar>bar 2</bar>
    <baz>baz 1</baz>
  </foo>
```

and when I change the code to

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:function name="mf:f1" as="node()*">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:param name="bar"/>
  <xsl:message select="'f1 called'"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$input//foo[bar = $bar]"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="mf:f2" as="node()*">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:param name="baz"/>
  <xsl:message select="'f2 called'"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$input//foo[baz = $baz]"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:variable name="a" select="mf:f1(/, 'bar x')"/>
<xsl:variable name="b" select="mf:f2(/, 'baz 1')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select="if ($a) then $a else $b"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then both functions are called:

```
f1 called
f2 called
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><foo>
    <bar>bar 2</bar>
    <baz>baz 1</baz>
  </foo>
```

Comment: I've just run this, and for all three of your samples, I'm getting messages that both f1 and f2 were called. I've run this on Saxon HE/PE/EE 9.6.0.5 in oXygen 17. I don't see any oXygen parameters that would prompt non lazy evaluation. I'm not sure why our results would differ.

Comment: I don't know details about Saxon in oXygen I am afraid but I am sure their support knows whether for debugging perhaps they run Saxon with some special settings preventing optimization.

Comment: I think that global variables are evaluated eagerly when tracing is enabled, and oXygen enables tracing (for use internally by its debugger). Generally, it's not a good idea to write code that relies on lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make a and b memo functions rather than global variables:

```
<function name="f:a" saxon:memo-function="yes">
 <xsl:sequence select="eg:quick-func()"/>
</function>
```